# link a href background size in an inline li

Tags: html, css, background, href

i have a navigation bar which i did with an inline display li

i want my last column to have a background with a defined height. But it gives me only a background behind the name of the column

here is the part of the style.css:

```
#navigation li {
display : inline;
}

#navigation a {
text-decoration : none;
font-family: 'Swiss_721_Condensed_BT';
font-size: 15px;
color:#0894D2;
padding-left: 12px;
padding-right: 12px;
}
```

here is the html

```
<li><a href="contact.php">CONTACTS</a></li>
<li><a href="contact.php" style="display:right;height:100px;line-weight:100px;      background:url(images/fond_testez_nous.png) ;"><font color=white>TESTEZ-NOUS</FONT>     </a></li>
```

here is the picture of the problem

[image]

i am looking for having the red part in blue as what is behind the text 'testez nous'

thanks for your help

Comment: there is no css property `display: right`. use `display: block` and `height: 100%;`

Comment: please avoid inline styles and tags for styling your document, it reduces the readability of your code.. [Why Use CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_Started/Why_use_CSS) 
also, your css selectors has an element `#navigation` which you haven't posted in your html… please provide the proper code or something like a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: try applying the background to li element rather than a

Comment: Do you just need a separate background **color** or specifically an image?

Comment: i need a separate background color. applying the background to li gave me the same result. #navigation is a div: <div id="navigation">
<ul>
 with the style.css:#navigation{

margin-left:100px;
margin-right:100px;

}

#navigation li {
display : inline;

}

Comment: or a table would have been better to do my navigation bar?

Comment: I'm not really sure if this is near to what you want - http://jsfiddle.net/Lc8DF/ - but let me know.

Answer (score 0):

use the following css like
ul:last-child{ background:red, height:20px; or styles which you wants to include}